# user_roles with features

Tags: 6, features, users

When I use `user_roles()` when there are roles added by features, the feature roles are not returned. How can I get a list of all roles on my site included those defined in features?

Answer (score 1):

Is the Role listed on `admin/user/roles`?  If not, your Feature might not be defining a Role, or the Feature might be overridden.

Roles defined by Features *do* actually show up in `user_roles()`.  I created a simple Feature defining a single role, then enabled it:

```
% drush php-eval "print_r(user_roles())"
Array
(
    [1] => anonymous user
    [2] => authenticated user
)

% drush pm-enable yayfeature
The following extensions will be enabled: yayfeature
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
yayfeature was enabled successfully.                                                                                          [ok]

% drush features-revert yayfeature
Do you really want to revert user_role? (y/n): y
Reverted user_role.                                                                                                           [ok]

% drush php-eval "print_r(user_roles())"
Array
(
    [1] => anonymous user
    [2] => authenticated user
    [5] => yay
)
```